# Jquery fade in and out with mouseover not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to make the text inside the div "tile_1_text" fade in when the mouse hovers over the animated contained in the div "man_1" and then have the image fade out once the mouse leaves. This is for a web design class and my professor wants us to use jquery but never taught it in class. I read as much as I could and my code is not working. Any help would be appreciated!

html

```
<body>
<div id="tile_1">
    <div id="man_1"> </div>
    <div id="man_1_arms"> </div>
</div>

<div id="tile_1_text">
    <p>This is my last piece of leather.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    body {
    background-image: url(../html%20files/background_image-01.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-family: "quicksand", "Arial", "Times New Roman";
    top: 79px;
    }

    #tile_1 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 768px; 
    background:url(tile%201/room-01.jpg);
    }

    #man_1 {
    background: url(tile%201/man_1.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 161px;
    left: 145px;
    width: 175px;
    height: 591px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #man_1_arms {
    background: url(tile%201/Man_1_arms-01.png);
    position: absolute;
    width: 276px;
    height: 326px;
    top: 203px;
    left: 87px;
    animation: right_arm_1 3s infinite alternate; transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-animation: right_arm_1 2s infinite alternate; 
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: quicksand;
    src:url(quicksand/Quicksand-Regular.otf)
    }

    @keyframes right_arm_1 {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(15deg);}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes right_arm_1 {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(15deg);}
    }

    @-moz-keyframes right_arm_1 {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(15deg);}
    }

    #tile_1_text {
    font-family:"quicksand", "Arial", "Times New Roman"; 
    font-size:45px;
    color:rgba(150,150,150,1.0);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    }
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#man_1").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("#tile_1_text").fadeIn(100);
}, function(){
        $(this).find("#tile_1_text").fadeOut(100)
});
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#man_1").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("#tile_1_text").fadeIn(100);
}, function(){
        $(this).find("#tile_1_text").fadeOut(100)
});
   });
```

- as your code: when hover on "#man_1", it will find "#tile_1_text" inside the "#man_1" and FadeIn. But according to your HTML code, "#tile_1_text" is not inside the "#man_1".
- you can try the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#man_1").hover(function(){
        $("#tile_1_text").fadeIn(100);
}, function(){
        $("#tile_1_text").fadeOut(100);
});
   });
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I had no idea that ".find" required the text to be inside "man_1." I've been trying to figure this out for the past five straight hours because the project is due tomorrow. I have such a limited understanding of jquery that its like a foreign language to me. You just saved me form getting a D on this!

Comment: I'm adding more picture elements to the design and I'm finding that the text is pushing everything down when it fades in. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should add a div outside the fadeIn content, ex:

<div style="position:relative;z-index:100;height:1px;" >
 <div id="tile_1_text" style="position:absolute;">
        <p>This is my last piece of leather.</p>
    </div>
</div>
.....

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#man_1").hover(function(){
       console.log("hey");
       $("#tile_1_text").fadeIn(100);
    }, function(){
       $("#tile_1_text").fadeOut(100);
    });
  })
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/floor_/1fu8o9wy/)